# Auto pull bitbucket private repository changes after every composer update

Tags: mercurial, zend-framework2, repository, composer-php, bitbucket

I have some problem with bitbucket private repository... So I've added something like this in my project root's `composer.json` :

```
"require": {
         "php" : ">=5.4.0",
            ...,
         "author/my-package": "0.2"
},

"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url":  "ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/author/my-package"
    }
    ...
]
```

So after `composer.phar update` it creates repo dir in `vendor`... But after new commit in private repository and composer.phar update in project's root it doesn't pull last changeset... It stays on head that was on first repository import

**Conclusion**

After composer.phar debugging I've understood that it doesn't update (pull) last changeset if package version hasn't been changed.

I've created script which updates every my repository after every composer update running. Info here https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md

```
<?php

namespace ComposerScript;

use Composer\Repository\RepositoryManager;
use Composer\Script\Event;
use Composer\Repository\PackageRepository;
use Composer\Package\CompletePackage;
use Composer\Util\ProcessExecutor;

class EventListener
{
    /**
 * @var ProcessExecutor
 */
protected static $processExecutor;

protected static $command = 'hg pull -u';

public static function getProcessExecutor()
{
    if (self::$processExecutor == null) {
        self::$processExecutor = new ProcessExecutor();
    }

    return self::$processExecutor;
}

public static function postUpdateCmd(Event $event)
{
    $composer = $event->getComposer();
    /** @var RepositoryManager $repositoryManager */
    $repositoryManager = $composer->getRepositoryManager();
    $cwd               = getcwd();

    foreach ($repositoryManager->getRepositories() as $repository) {
        if ($repository instanceof PackageRepository) {
            foreach ($repository->getPackages() as $package) {
                /** @var CompletePackage $package */
                $vendorName     = explode('/', $package->getName())[0];
                $repositoryPath = $cwd . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'vendor' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $package->getName();

                if ($package->getSourceType() == 'hg' && $vendorName == 'myvendor' && is_dir($repositoryPath)) {
                    echo PHP_EOL . "Trying to execute '".self::$command."' in '".$repositoryPath . "'" . PHP_EOL;
                    $exitCode = self::getProcessExecutor()->execute(self::$command, $output, $repositoryPath);
                    if ($exitCode !== 0) {
                        echo "Unable to execute '" . self::$command . "' command in '" . $repositoryPath . "' dir" .
                            PHP_EOL .
                            "Message: " .
                            PHP_EOL .
                            $output;
                    } else {
                        echo 'Success';
                    }
                }
            }

            echo PHP_EOL;
        }
        }
    }
}
```

And added few lines to composer.json

```
"autoload"    : {
    "psr-0": {
        "ComposerScript\\EventListener" : ""
    }
},
"scripts" : {
    "post-update-cmd" : [
        "ComposerScript\\EventListener::postUpdateCmd"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've told composer to install version 0.2 of your package, so that's what it's done. This won't change if you run update. If you want to track a branch instead, change the version to `dev-master`:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    ...,
    "author/my-package": "dev-master"
},
```

Comment: but I haven't no dev, no master branches, tags etc.

Comment: By default, it'll be the default branch. So perhaps you can use "default" instead of "dev-master"?

Comment: @Mathiasdm but what is difference between default and 0.2?
I've tried to create master bookmark, tag, branch etc, branch-alias in composer.json - "dev-master"  : "0.2-dev"... but nothing helps... Perhaps  this is feature of private repositories...

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the output of `git branch -a` and `git tag -l` run from the root of your project. This will list all branches and tags you have.

Comment: @tim-fountain first of all I use mercurial and the second I've tried a lot... so I want to see example...